# devtool::test() gives warning, R CMD check ok

Tags: r, devtools, testthat

`devtools::test()` gives me a warning each time one of my internal function is ran. But when I run the incriminated codes in the console there is no warning. In addition `R CMD check` or `devtools::check()` don't complain about these lines of code (no error, no warning, no note).

So it means that `devtools::test()` run the tests using different settings compared to the regular R environment and compared to `R CMD check`.

I investigated and I didn't find any hint even if I found several topics with more a less comparable questions. This is not really a problem because the outputs are good and the problem does not occur on CRAN or when running the code. But I would like to remove these warning from `devtools::test()`.

Please note that my question does not concern how to fix the warnings but how to get a chance to reproduce the problem in attempt to solve it.

Comment: Have you also used `R CMD check --as-cran`?

Comment: Yes I always check `--as-cran`.